# Unable to Install Postal Mail Server on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: command-line, server, putty, smtp

I am using Digital Ocean VPS, having Ubuntu 20.04.1 and I am trying to build a new SMTP on Postal using Putty (SSH).

When I copy paste the following command to install Postal, it is given me the error (screenshot attached).

Command: **curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/atech/postal/master/script/install/ubuntu1604.sh | sh**

Error Screenshot:
[Error on using above command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJIRA.png)

I tried to searched the errors, but as I am not a programming geek, so I need help about it.

When I saw the command carefully, it is for Ubuntu 16.04 version but I am using Ubuntu 20.04 version so I modify the command in:

**curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/atech/postal/master/script/install/ubuntu2004.sh | sh**

...and this time I got this error:

[Error getting on using 2nd command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrb1Y.png)

Now, I am stuck here and I want to solve this error so I can have a clean installation of Postal.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: The software don't have support for Ubuntu 20.04 or the URL you constructed for 20.04 isn't correct.

Comment: I have created a server some days back using the same SSH software for Ubuntu 20.04 and that server was created on Virtualmin.

If we look on commands, both are same and I have just change the version from 1604 to 2004

Comment: You can't "just change the version" ... `ubuntu1004.sh` is the name of a file on the web-server. You can't be sure that there are one for 20.04 too.

Comment: Thanks for your comment!

But when I was using ubuntu1604.sh as recommended by Postal, why it is giving me the error? It must has to be install.